# when i want to use guna.ui2.licensing in visual studio 2019. it's showing this kind of error. what i want to do for solving this issue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio

Failed to create component 'Guna2Elipse . The error message
follows:

"Microsoft. DotNet.DesignTools. Client. DesignToolsServerExcep
tion: Could not load type

System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext

from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

at

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry. WindowsErrorReporting.Wa
tsonReport. GetCirWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)"